# Rationalising the denominator problem

Tags: fractions, rationalising-denominator

I need help rationalising this

$$\frac{4}{(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt[4]{5}+1)(\sqrt[8]{5}+1)(\sqrt[16]{5}+1) }$$

I'm so stuck with this problem!

Comment: Treat it like a product of four fractions.  Rationalize the denominator of each factor, and multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deepest root is the place to start.  Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt[16]5-1$.  You don't have any more sixteenth roots, so this is progress.  Keep going.

Comment: Once you remove the sixteenth root others will automatically be removed from the formula $(a+b)(a-b) =a^2 - b^2$

Comment: @Abhinav:  this step leaves us with some eighth roots.  Now we rationalize those and get down to fourth roots.